# Assign ggplot2 layers to string and evaluate if needed

Tags: r, ggplot2

### Background

I am trying to speed up a function for [an R package that plots high-resolution maps](https://github.com/MikkoVihtakari/PlotSvalbard) using ggplot2. The function `basemap` plots a map of Svalbard using shapefiles that are large (15 Mb each). The map is created using two different layers of shapefiles, land and glaciers, and a set of "definitions", such as theme, axis scales and grid lines. Plotting the map, as the code is written now, takes about 30 seconds.

My idea is that, if I could break the layers in code-pieces and allow the user a possibility not to plot glaciers, the function would perform twice as fast. If I, in addition, could assign the ggplot2 syntax as text string and evaluate only the strings that are needed, R would not waste time making ggplot2 objects that are not used by the function.

I know how to do this using `if else` statements, but I would like to avoid writing the definitions several times. It seems to be possible to assign `scale_x_continuous()` to an object, but assigning `scale_x_continuous() + scale_y_continuous()` produces an error:

> Error in scale_x_continuous() + scale_y_continuous() : 
>     non-numeric argument to binary operator

### Question

How do I assign ggplot2 axis definitions to a text string and paste them together with data layers?

### Example

I use the `iris` dataset as an example, so that you do not have to download the [`PlotSvalbard`](https://github.com/MikkoVihtakari/PlotSvalbard) package that is large and quite messy at the moment. Note that I know how to map color to a variable. The point here is just to illustrate the shapefiles as two subsets of the `iris` dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(iris)

## Datasets to imitate the shapefile layers
ds1 <- subset(iris, Species == "setosa")
ds2 <- subset(iris, Species == "versicolor")

## Example how the basemap function works at the moment:

ggplot() + geom_point(data = ds1, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width), color = "red") +
geom_point(data = ds2, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width), color = "blue") +
scale_x_continuous("Longitude", breaks = seq(3, 8, by = 0.5)) +
scale_y_continuous("Latitude", breaks = seq(1,5, by = 1)) + theme_bw()

## Now I would like to plot ds2 only if user defines "keep.glaciers = TRUE"

land <- ggplot() + geom_point(data = ds1, aes(x = Sepal.Length, 
y = Sepal.Width), color = "red")

glacier <- geom_point(data = ds2, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width),
 color = "blue")

def <- scale_x_continuous("Longitude", breaks = seq(3, 8, by = 0.5)) +
scale_y_continuous("Latitude", breaks = seq(1,5, by = 1)) + theme_bw() ## Error!
# Error in +scale_x_continuous("Longitude", breaks = seq(3, 8, by = 0.5)) :
#  invalid argument to unary operator

## The ultimate goal:
keep.glaciers = TRUE

if(keep.glaciers) {
  land + glacier + def # error, see above
} else {
  land + def
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign ggplot2 layers to strings and evaluate the strings after pasting them together:

```
map_layers <- function(layer) {

   switch(layer, 
    land = 'ggplot() + geom_point(data = ds1, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width), color = "red")',
    glacier = 'geom_point(data = ds2, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width), color = "blue")',
    def = 'scale_x_continuous("Longitude", breaks = seq(3, 8, by = 0.5)) + scale_y_continuous("Latitude", breaks = seq(1,5, by = 1)) + theme_bw()',
    stop(paste("map layer", layer, "not found"))
)
}

plot_glaciers <- function(keep.glaciers = TRUE) {

    if(keep.glaciers) {
      eval(parse(text=paste(map_layers("land"), map_layers("glacier"),
 map_layers("def"), sep = " + ")))
        } else {
      eval(parse(text=paste(map_layers("land"), map_layers("def"), sep = " + ")))
    }
}

plot_glaciers()
plot_glaciers(FALSE)
```

Using the nested `switch` approach allows you to make "modules" that you can easily paste together in `if else` statements of the plot function making the code easier to read, if you want to pass many map layers to the plot function.

Comment: I think you should keep the question but edit it. Either fix the alternative approach or remove it altogether from the question and instead put it into this answer. There’s no reason to leave a known typo in the question.

Comment: @ClausWilke. Thank you for your comment. I edited the question and my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

You can keep layers in a `list` and use the `+` operator with `ggplot`.

For example, the function `plot_glaciers` keeps the `land`, `def`, and `glacier` layers in a list.  A `if` statement controls the construction of the `glacier` layer.  The function will return the `ggplot` object with the wanted layers.

```
plot_glaciers <- function(keep_glaciers = TRUE) {
  layers <- vector('list')

  layers$land    <- geom_point(data = ds1, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width), color = "red")
  layers$def     <- list(scale_x_continuous("Longitude", breaks = seq(3, 8, by = 0.5)),
                    scale_y_continuous("Latitude", breaks = seq(1,5, by = 1)),
                    theme_bw())

  if (keep_glaciers) {
    layers$glacier <- geom_point(data = ds2, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width), color = "blue")
  } 

  ggplot() + layers
}

plot_glaciers(TRUE)
plot_glaciers(FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Programmatically joining ggplot2 layers is something I’ve pondered for a long time but never really investigated. I have all sorts of uses for this type of code.